# Core Data: fetching from related entity

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-data

I have one to one relationship with User and Company table. I am trying to get the data of company via User predicate. I am creating a simple UI on storyboard and searching for name. And via using this name attribute, i want to know the number and company attribute associated with this. I can get the number attribute but i am not able to get the company attribute.

This is the added source code for where i want to fetch the attributes

[image: Please check the console image for the returned value]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you include the code a text instead of an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the company name simply by navigating the relationship to it:

```
companyname.text = res.valueForKeyPath("company.companyName") as? String
```

Comment: Thanks Wain! I would like to know in case of multi relationship? 
companyname.text = res.valueForKeyPath("company[0].companyName") as? String
is it ok?

Comment: Then you have a set of companies for a use and you need to deal with the multiplicity separately. Technically `valueForKeyPath` would work and return you an `NSSet` of company names in this case... You can't index into an array in `valueForKeyPath`

Comment: @A-man I know this was a simple question/answer, but was the answer really good enough to be accepted, but not good enough to pass the "this answer is useful" requirement to get an up vote from you?